# Batch file using variable %%f in nested loop fails

Tags: batch-file

Im very confused at what's going on here. It should copy all docx found from docs to working directory. but for some reason the %%f inside the for loop shows up as %f. i did an echo and it printed out the folder just fine. the same thing happens to %%r and %r as well. I'm I writing this incorrectly?

```
set filepath=%1
for /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b %filepath%') do (
if exist "%filepath%\%%f\docs" (
for /r %filepath%\%%f\docs %%r in (*.docx) do (
echo %%f
copy %%r "%cd%\edited"
)
)
)
```

The output

```
if exist "C:\Documents\WordDocs\Data1\docs" (for /R C:\Documents\WordDocs\%f\docs %r in (*.docx) do ( 
echo Data1
copy %r "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Test"
) ) )
```

Comment: but the output display it as %f instead of Data1. do i just use %f instead of %%f?

Comment: up until the if statement it works fine. its when i tried to use the %%f inside the nested for loop it prints out %f instead of the value it's supposed to be.

Comment: This is an interesting problem! It seems to be some limitation on the `FOR /R` command, rather than anything to do with the `%` sign. Perhaps the `for /r` command only allows literal parameters and not variables?

Comment: Let me paraphrase your issue so that other readers can appreciate it. Simply put, the following command does not work: `for %%f in (C:\Windows) do (for /r "%%f" %%r in (*.tmp) do (echo %%r))`

Comment: I noticed this issue many years ago now and was completely perplexed by it. _It's also one of the reasons, I try to use `%%A` whenever possible_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version doesn't use `For /R`:

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir/B/AD-L "%~1"') Do If Exist "%~1\%%A\docs\" (
    For /F "Delims=" %%B In ('Dir/B/S/A-D-L "%~1\%%A\docs\*.docx"'
    ) Do Echo=Copy "%%~B" "%CD%\edited")
Pause
```

Remove line 4 and `Echo=` on line 3 if you're happy with the output in the cmd window, *remembering to unedit your destination path*.

Answer (score 2):

The [`for` command](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) (like the [`if` command](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)) is parsed earlier than other commands. At this time, `for` variable references like `%%f` are not yet recognised. So [`for /R`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) cannot use a root path containing a `for` variable reference like `%%f`. The same is true for the option string of [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html). You can also not use a [delayed expanded variable](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) instead of `%%f`.

The easiest work-around for the script at hand is to use [`pushd`](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)`"%filepath%\%%f\docs"` before the `for /R` loop and [`popd`](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) after it, and to let `for /R` use its default root, namely the current working directory, which has just been set by `pushd`; the previous one becomes restored by `popd`. Here is a demonstration of what I mean:

```cmd
set "filepath=%~1"
for /F %%f in ('dir /A:D /B "%filepath%"') do (
    if exist "%filepath%\%%f\docs" (
        pushd "%filepath%\%%f\docs"
        for /R %%r in ("*.docx") do (
            echo/%%f
            copy "%%~r" "%cd%\edited"
        )
        popd
    )
)
```

An alternative but more complicated way is to move the `for /R` loop into a sub-routine, to call it by the [`call` command](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) and to pass the root path as an [argument](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html), like this:

```cmd
set "filepath=%~1"
for /F %%f in ('dir /A:D /B "%filepath%"') do (
    if exist "%filepath%\%%f\docs" (
        call :SUB "%filepath%\%%f\docs"
    )
)
goto :EOF

:SUB
for /R "%~1" %%r in ("*.docx") do (
    echo/%%f
    copy "%%~r" "%cd%\edited"
)
goto :EOF
```

Reference this post: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133)